# No Version tab when right-click Properties of an executable or DLL file?

Tags: windows-xp, version

I seem to have lost the Version tab when I right-click .exe or .dll files and select Properties. I now just get the tabs: General, Compatibility, Security and Summary.

Running a fully-patched Windows XP SP3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some DLLs do not include a version resource, thus no Version tab.  Try the same thing with a DLL in your Windows\System32 directory.  Are you sure you've lost that Version tab for *all* DLLs/EXEs?

Comment: Doh. I naively assumed that all .exe and .dll files would produce a Version tab regardless of whether the author had included this info. Cheers.